# Traverse JSON data in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I am new to JSON..Am using HTTPUrlConnections and getting some response in JAVA program.The response data will be like,

```
    {
    "data": [
        {
    "id": 1,
            "userId": 1,
            "name": "ABC",
            "modified": "2014-12-04",
            "created": "2014-12-04",
            "items": [
                {
                    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
                    "links": [
                        {
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
            }
        ]
}
```

From this response am able to get the value of "**name**" field with the below java code.

```
JSONArray items = newObj.getJSONArray("data");
for (int it=0 ; it < items.length() ; it++){
    JSONObject contactItem = items.getJSONObject(it);
    String userName = contactItem.getString("name");
    System.out.println("Name----------"+userName);
}
```

But my requirement is,I need to get the value of "**email**" ..How should I code for that..
Any advice..

Thanks in advance..
Chitra

Comment: please refer [this](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/11/json-to-hashmap-parsing-json-string.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first get the `items` array and each entry of this array contains `JSONObject`, from which you can call `getString("email")` .E.g.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class App
{

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject newObj = new JSONObject("{" +
                "\"data\": [\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "\"id\": 1,\n" +
                "        \"userId\": 1,\n" +
                "        \"name\": \"ABC\",\n" +
                "        \"modified\": \"2014-12-04\",\n" +
                "        \"created\": \"2014-12-04\",\n" +
                "        \"items\": [\n" +
                "            {\n" +
                "                \"email\": \"abc@gmail.com\",\n" +
                "                \"links\": [\n" +
                "                    {\n" +

                "                    }\n" +
                "                ]\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "        ]\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "\n" +
                "}");



        JSONArray items = newObj.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int it = 0; it < items.length(); it++) {
            JSONObject contactItem = items.getJSONObject(it);
            String userName = contactItem.getString("name");


            JSONArray item = contactItem.getJSONArray("items");

            for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                String email = item.getJSONObject(i).getString("email");
                System.out.println(email);
            }

            System.out.println("Name----------" + userName);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
abc@gmail.com
Name----------ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending your logic only:

```
JSONArray items = newObj.getJSONArray("data");
for (int it=0 ; it < items.length() ; it++){
    JSONObject contactItem = items.getJSONObject(it);
    String userName = contactItem.getString("name");
    System.out.println("Name----------"+userName);

    JSONArray itemsArr = contactItem.getJSONArray("items");
    for (int item=0 ; item < itemsArr.length() ; item++){
        String email = item.getString("email");
        System.out.println("Email----------"+email);
    }

}
```

This should work, with few tweaks. I have not actually tested it, just writing freehand here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Jackson library from FasterXML. You can convert the JSON String into Java object very easily and then you can traverse using iterations on Collections.

Answer (score 0):

If you look the JSON String it contains `items` which can be considered as an Array within an Array, so in order to get the value of `email` all you need to do is to create another `JSONArray` like:

```
JSONArray itemsArray = contactItem.getJSONArray("items");
```

Then you can retrieve the value of `email` over this Array

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your time and response.
The below code did the magic:

```
JSONArray responseContactData = responseContact.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i=0; i < responseContactData.length(); i++) {
    String emails = contactDataValues.getJSONArray("items").getJSONObject(0).getString("email");
}
```