# JSON traversing in java

Tags: java, json

i want traverse and get particular value from the json i am giving below .

```
json={"resultMessage":["{\"retain24ErrorMessage\":\"No result data found!\"}","TemplateId or instanceId is empty!"],"isSuccessful":true}
```

The value i want to get is retain24ErrorMessage value. I have tried the following.

```
Object JSONArrayCheck = json.get("resultMessage");
                        String errMsg1 = (String)json.getJSONArray("resultMessage").get(0);
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
//                      JsonElement jsonObject = gson.toJsonTree(json.getJSONArray("resultMessage").get(0));
                         JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(gson.toJson(errMsg1));
                            JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
```

But is not working and following error comes

```
12-11 17:17:16.300: W/System.err(1780): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "{\"retain24ErrorMessage\":\"No result data found!\"}"
```

. Can you give me demo for retrieving the same retain24ErrorMessage ?

Comment: Please replace "But is not working" with whatever actually happens. When you go to the doctor, do you tell him "My lower right arm hurts" or just "I don't feel well"?

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353664/traverse-json-data-in-java/27353895#27353895 . Probably will be helpful.

Comment: This, BTW, is what's known as "embedded JSON".

Answer (score 1):

`gson.toJson(errMsg1)` expects an Object but the passed `errMsg1` is a string.

Don't you need to do something like this instead?

```
JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(errMsg1);
```